# Lucid Lynx or Saucy Salamander?

Tags: installation, 12.10, compatibility

I've got a macbook from 2008, which blue-screened, onto which I installed Ubuntu 12.10 from the Ubuntu magazine disk. It is slow. It freezes continuously. It only runs select Internet pages well (like gmail is constantly unable to run script).
I'd like to know if there is a problem between the software and hardware such that I should and could pick an older version of Linux (like Lynx) and install that, or if installing from the magazine disc really isn't enough (like that's all I did, just the disc and called it good -- it makes it seem too easy).

Answer (score 1):

I preferred saucy salamendar . here is some key features of 13.10 . and just few day ago i installed cinnamon on 13.10 and that is awesome . hope you like it . here is the link
ubuntu 13.10 key features:
http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/ubuntu-13-10-review-the-linux-os-of-the-future-remains-a-year-away/
and for cinnamon :
http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would ask myself what do I want my computer to do? Am I going to play games or do online banking. 12.04 is great by me but may be compatability is a difficulty, when it comes to apps. My laptop is loaded with Windows 8 and Ubu 12.04. It makes it starting each time, and playing games, music and surfing is what I use it for. Perhaps the errors it has are due to compatibility, IDK, good topic. I am looking at this:[> G <](http://ultimateedition.info/)

I would also install http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/ , which gives us an idea of optional installs/

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin. 
It is stable (12.04.3 now) and will be supported until 2017.
It has Unity, GNOME 3.4 and GNOME fallback, with extra-pane in Nautilus, full keyboard layout customizations, usb devices safely-remove.

There is no practical reason to update to regular (non LTS) release.